# How are explicit compilition flags used for optimization nowadays?

Tags: go

The goal is compile a binary for production. I've found out that some flags, such as `-l` that used to be used, no longer supported.

How are explicit compilition flags used for optimization nowadays? Or is it optimized by default?

Comment: `-l` -means disable inlining. that isn't "optimization", otherwise, inlining helps you to make fewer CPU instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How are explicit compilition flags used for optimization nowadays?

No flags are use for optimization when compiling production code nowadays.

> Or is it optimized by default?

The standard Go compiler gc is an optimizing compiler by default.